# Deploying a Java based Lambda package to S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working on a Lambda project in Java. Actually, I have already packaged it as a jar. As part of the deployment, I would like to upload this jar to s3 bucket.

While setting up the lambda function, I would like to specify the s3 key of the uploaded jar. I have seen quite a few examples over the internet. But most of them talk about either Js or Python. A few of the articles are there also related to Java but do not specify concretely how to do this.

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

**EDIT**

I am using Terraform to create my lambda function, where I have to pass the s3 bucket along with the s3 key of the uploaded Lambda jar.

Comment: Did you read the canonical documentation? See [Deploy Java Lambda functions with .zip or JAR file archives](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html).

Comment: what tool you are using to create lambda function? cloudformation, cdk, etc ?

Comment: The Lambda developer guide, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html, has a ton of examples of writing Lambda functions in various programming languages using various AWS SDKs (see "Working with ...". Unfortunately, many of them are for older SDKs, so you might have to crack open an SDK's developer guide to find information about porting say a Java1 code example to Java2.

Comment: @jarmod Yes, I have read this. But in this article, it is not clearly mentioned, how to upload the lambda package to s3 which I can use in Terraform in order to create the lambda function.

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I have updated the OP. I am using Terraform in order to create the lambda function.

Comment: @DougSchwartz Thanks. I have gone through the article you shared. Actually, I am looking for deploying my lambda package to s3 so that I can use it in Terraform while creating the lambda function

Comment: If you simply need to upload the ZIP package to S3 so you can reference it when deploying the Lambda function then use the awscli to copy the ZIP to a suitable S3 bucket. Also, maybe read https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/lambda-api-gateway

Comment: @jarmod thanks. Here in the shared link, I can see, only the zip is being created out of main.js. But in my case, i.e. for Java-based Lambda, should I create a Zip of the jar or only the Java class containing the lambda handler? I am asking because, I have tried the first one, i.e. creating Zip out of the Jar, but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

There are various articles that show you how to use the Java Lambda runtime API to build Lambda functions that perform various use cases. These are in the Java V2 Github repo:

1 - [Creating an Amazon Web Services Lambda function that tags digital assets located in Amazon S3 buckets](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_tag_assets)

2 - [Using AWS Step Functions and the AWS SDK for Java to build workflows that sends notifications over multiple channels](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/workflow_multiple_channels)

3- [Creating scheduled events to invoke Lambda functions](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events)

All of these examples provide you with step by step instructions and show you how to build Lambda functions using the Lambda Java runtime API that interact with other AWS Services. For example, the 1st one shows you how to build a Lambda function that can ***automatically*** tag images in an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I have gone through the articles you shared. Actually, I am looking for deploying my lambda package to s3 so that I can use it in Terraform while creating the lambda function.